# Error running csh on Red Hat 6.9

Tags: linux, redhat, fpga, csh

I recently took over a project to finish that executes a csh script during its make process, and would fail at this point with the following error:

> .alias: No such file or directory.

This error appears to be unrelated to this specific makefile because I receive the same error when trying to open the csh interpreter, even while inside the /bin directory. Below is a screenshot example. Any ideas on where to look for the cause of this error is appreciated. The tcsh has the same issue, but bash runs without any issues.

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: Try checking your `~/.cshrc` and `~/.login` files.

Comment: Thanks, found the error in the ~/.cshrc file.